# C program stops execution when assigning variable

Tags: c, avr, atmega

I'm not sure if this is happening when assigning a variable specifically but when debugging the assembly code, the compiler executes `RJMP $+0000` where it hangs the program.

EDIT: I added included libraries if that's relevant

```c
#define __DELAY_BACKWARD_COMPATIBLE__
#define F_CPU 8000000UL
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <avr/delay.h>
#include <stdint.h> 

void ReadTemp(uint8_t address){
    
    ADCSRA = ADCSRA | 0b10000111;       //enable ADC, CLK/128 conversion speed
    ADMUX  = ADMUX | 0b01000000;        //Use internal 2.56V Vref and PA0 as input, right-hand justified
        
    ADCSRA |= (1 << ADSC);              //start conversion
        
    while(!(ADCSRA & (1 << ADIF))) {}   // wait until process is finished;

    uint8_t  low_value = ADC & 0x00FF;
// or low_value = ADCL;
    uint8_t high_value = ADC & 0xFF00;   //problem here
...
}
```

[image]

Comment: It is strange that the C code shows `uint8_t  low_value` but the asssembly code shows `int low_value`. Are you sure they are from the same source?

Comment: I was testing different variable types to see if it worked. Don't worry same issue still persists

Comment: So why the mis-matching codes? It's not from the same C program.

Comment: Perhaps the compiler thinks that the value of `!(ADCSRA & (1 << ADIF))` established by the pre-compiler is always `true`.

Comment: I fixed the variable mismatch. Also, I don't believe that's the case because execution point gets past that line. I get the result if I store to the EEPROM.

Comment: Could it be an issue with compiler optimization?

Comment: Having 'fixed' the posted code, it is still strange why the assembler is making reads from adjacent registers, as though it still reading a 16-bit value.

Comment: well I think I fixed it by changing optimization to -O0

Comment: can someone explain to me how `uint8_t high_value = ADC & 0xFF00;` isn't always zero? It's storing the value in 8 bits. But it's `and`ing the LSB with zero. It should always be zero. the mask 0xFF00 is 16 bit. Shouldn't he be shifting the result right by 8? (`uint8_t high_value = (ADC & 0xFF00) >> 8;`)

Comment: that's correct, it works with lower byte but not high byte. I guess in this case, changing it to `uint8_t high_value = ADCH;` would be a better option.

Comment: `RJMP $+0` is an instruction that jumps to itself, causing your program to do an infinite loop.  Without seeing the full code, we can only guess about what the compiler would compile your code to an infinite loop.  Please provide a [MCVE].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is something somewhat suboptimal here:

```c
uint8_t low_value = ADC & 0x00FF;
```

You are reading `ADC`, which is a 16-bit register, implemented as a pair
of 8-bit registers. As shown in the disassembly, this requires two `in`
instructions, one per byte. And then you are just throwing away one of
those bytes. You may think that the compiler is smart enough to avoid
reading the byte it is going to discard right away. Unfortunately, it
cannot do that, as I/O registers are declared as `volatile`. The
compiler is forced to access the register as many times as the source
code does.

If you just want the low byte, you should read only that byte:

```c
uint8_t low_value = ADCL;
```

You then wrote:

```c
uint8_t high_value = ADC & 0xFF00;
```

As explained in the previous answer, `high_value` will be zero. Yet the
compiler will have to read the two bytes again, because the I/O register
is `volatile`. If you want to read the high byte, read `ADCH`.

But why would you want to read those two bytes one by one? Is it to put
them back together into a 16-bit variable? If this is the case, then
there is no need to read them separately. Instead, just read the 16-bit
register in the most straight-forward fashion:

```c
uint16_t value = ADC;
```

A long time ago, gcc didn't know how to handle 16-bit registers, and
people had to resort to reading the bytes one by one, and then gluing
them together. You may still find very old example code on the Internet
that does that. Today, there is absolutely no reason to continue
programming this way.

Then you wrote:

```c
//problem here
```

Nope, the problem is not here. That is not what generated the `rjmp`
instruction. The problem is probably right after that line, in the code
you have chosen not to post. You have some bug that manifests itself
only when optimizations are turned on. This is typical of code that
produces *undefined behavior*: works as expected with optimizations off,
then does weird “unexplainable” things when you enable optimizations.

Answer (score 6):

I don't know what any of this is doing, but I do see an error in the bitwise math.

```
uint8_t  low_value = ADC & 0x00FF;
uint8_t high_value = ADC & 0xFF00;   //problem here
```

`low_value` and `high_value` are both 8 bits (`uint8_t`). I am going to go out on a limb here and say `ADC` is 16 bit. For `high_value`, you are `and`ing ADC with `0xFF00` then truncating the value to 8 bit. `high_value` will always be zero.

What should be done is:

```
uint8_t high_value = (ADC & 0xFF00) >> 8;
```

This will grab the left byte of ADC and shift it right by 8 bits then assign it to the `high_value` byte storage giving you the correct value.

How you are doing `low_value` is correct. As a matter of fact, you could simply do:

```
uint8_t low_value = ADC;
```